# Posting form elements that aren't visible in DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using a jQuery plug-in called Datatables on a table contained within a form, and this table will contain many form elements.

I have a Save Changes button on the page, which will execute an AJAX request to update the database based on what the user has entered.

The problem I have is that it will only post the form element that are currently visible in the Datatable. In an example I have, there are 74 rows (all containing several fields). The default amount of records to show is 10.

So when the form is submitted only form elements of 10 rows are submitted. I was to submit the fields of all the rows - in this case all 74 rows worth of fields.

Does anyone have a solution for this? THanks.

Comment: are you using a server side source for your table ?

Comment: I'm using classic ASP to build the table.

Comment: What i mean is - are you getting the hidden rows from the server each time or do you output the whole table and then datatables paginate for you ?

Comment: Oh right, I don't hide any rows server-side. I let Datatables do all the paging.

Comment: @ManseUK datatables handles the paging and destroys the hidden rows.

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti thats what I was aiming towards - i thought maybe the OP was using server side processing and would need to submit the changes on each page change ... just out of interest - where/how does Datatables store the "hidden" rows ?

Comment: @ManseUK into a jsArray i think, and that array lives into the dataTable object.

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti ok no probs - your method below explains most of it ... i guess i could look at the source of `_fnGetTrNodes`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Datatables destroys the hidden rows and takes them out of the DOM. If you need to do a submit, you should use fnGetHiddenNodes() to retrieve the hidden rows before submitting. take a look at the [api](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api) pages

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnGetHiddenNodes = function ( oSettings )
{
    /* Note the use of a DataTables 'private' function thought the 'oApi' object */
    var anNodes = this.oApi._fnGetTrNodes( oSettings );
    var anDisplay = $('tbody tr', oSettings.nTable);

    /* Remove nodes which are being displayed */
    for ( var i=0 ; i<anDisplay.length ; i++ )
    {
        var iIndex = jQuery.inArray( anDisplay[i], anNodes );
        if ( iIndex != -1 )
        {
            anNodes.splice( iIndex, 1 );
        }
    }

    /* Fire back the array to the caller */
    return anNodes;
}
```

Comment: Great thanks. Was looking for this code in the documentation, and couldn't find it. Quick question what's the different between `jQuery.inArray` and `$.inArray`?

Comment: @GarethLewis they are exactly the same thing, `$` is an alias for `jQuery`

Comment: OK, if I understand the idea, what should I do with the anNodes to submit the form? I have to somehow attach every row to the table again?

Comment: @El_Hoy My table had checkboxes so I used it in this way 
`var hiddenCheckboxes = $(oTable.fnGetHiddenNodes()).find('input[type=checkbox]:checked');`
This will return all checkboxes which were checked. Then send this data alongwith AJAX data.